# Tabularx with m columns but not for headers

Tags: tabularx

I have the following table for which I would like to center horizontally and vertically the contents of each cell. However I would like to not vertically center the headings, they should be aligned to the bottom of the heading cell. I'm using tabularx for the second column.

Using the following code, the headings are not all aligned to the bottom. How can I align all the headings to the bottom while keeping the content cells this way? The line emphasized with comments causes this problem, but also seems to be the only way to vertically center the cells. [image: With line 2] [image: Without line 2, this is how the headings should be.]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}X}%
  \newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

  %%% The line for vertical centering
  \def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
  %%% ------

  \begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Table of results}
  \label{tbl:listexperiments}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!18}{white}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cCcccccccccc}
  \rowcolor{gray!40}
  \rot{\emph{Experiment number}}
  & \rot{\emph{Time scales}}\
  & \rot{\emph{Hidden units}}
  & \rot{\emph{Prediction length (samples)}}
  & \rot{\emph{Sample length (minutes)}}
  & \rot{\emph{Input sequence length (samples)}}
  & \rot{\emph{Model training steps (1000s)}}
  & \rot{\emph{Training time (hours)}}
  & \rot{\emph{Loss value}}
  & \rot{\emph{Next Type Error}}
  & \rot{\emph{Next Switch MSE}}
  & \rot{\emph{Next Switch RMSE}}\\
  \#721
  & \footnotesize{[1, 32]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 80.1
  & 14.14
  & 0.751
  & 0.364
  & 1570.8
  & -9.043\\
  \#724
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 10.1
  & 1.98
  & 0.818
  & 0.408
  & 1707.9
  & -8.212\\
  \#727
  & \footnotesize{[1]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 230.1
  & 39.51
  & 0.838
  & 0.346
  & 1853.8
  & -14.215\\
  \#730
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 180.1
  & 33.88
  & 0.845
  & 0.405
  & 1753.2
  & -8.222\\
  \#742
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 48
  & 14
  & 9
  & 512
  & 5.1
  & 0.51
  & 0.864
  & 0.422
  & 1688.2
  & -5.685\\
  \#745
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 48
  & 14
  & 9
  & 512
  & 1.0
  & 0.13
  & 1.038
  & 0.414
  & 2069.8
  & -4.907\\
  \#748
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 48
  & 14
  & 9
  & 512
  & 22.6
  & 2.14
  & 0.841
  & 0.431
  & 1678.6
  & -6.614\\
  \#751
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 48
  & 14
  & 9
  & 512
  & 2.6
  & 0.29
  & 0.893
  & 0.433
  & 1844.3
  & -3.705\\
  \#754
  & \footnotesize{[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 0.1
  & 0.13
  & 1.254
  & 0.461
  & 2661.1
  & 5.821\\
  \#757
  & \footnotesize{[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 325.1
  & 93.51
  & 0.814
  & 0.381
  & 1736.5
  & -10.174\\
  \#760
  & \footnotesize{[1, 16]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 60.1
  & 11.30
  & 0.811
  & 0.387
  & 1657.5
  & -7.984\\
  \#763
  & \footnotesize{[1, 3, 9, 18, 36, 72]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1080
  & 45.1
  & 11.50
  & 0.795
  & 0.377
  & 1751.9
  & -10.839\\
  \#768
  & \footnotesize{[1]}
  & 96
  & 5
  & 72
  & 128
  & 245.1
  & 8.02
  & 1.151
  & 0.529
  & 26301.8
  & -38.075\\
  \#769
  & \footnotesize{[1]}
  & 96
  & 5
  & 72
  & 128
  & 47.6
  & 1.58
  & 1.133
  & 0.530
  & 25688.5
  & -32.278\\
  \#770
  & \footnotesize{[1]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 18
  & 512
  & 87.6
  & 8.32
  & 1.085
  & 0.528
  & 10844.1
  & -36.840\\
  \#771
  & \footnotesize{[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 15.1
  & 4.47
  & 0.810
  & 0.397
  & 1737.2
  & -9.246\\
  \#772
  & \footnotesize{[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 17.6
  & 5.27
  & 0.835
  & 0.400
  & 1720.5
  & -9.170\\
  \#773
  & \footnotesize{[1, 16]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 15.1
  & 2.84
  & 0.817
  & 0.400
  & 1658.7
  & -7.184\\
  \#774
  & \footnotesize{[1, 64]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 17.6
  & 3.23
  & 0.877
  & 0.393
  & 1724.9
  & -9.322\\
  \#775
  & \footnotesize{[1, 32]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 22.6
  & 4.15
  & 0.764
  & 0.365
  & 1630.3
  & -9.681\\
  \#776
  & \footnotesize{[1, 32]}
  & 48
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 1.0
  & 0.23
  & 1.030
  & 0.445
  & 2013.5
  & -4.622\\
  \#777
  & \footnotesize{[1, 9, 36]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1080
  & 35.1
  & 7.21
  & 0.802
  & 0.392
  & 1708.3
  & -8.549\\
  \#778
  & \footnotesize{[1, 16, 64]}
  & 96
  & 14
  & 9
  & 1024
  & 47.6
  & 8.94
  & 0.747
  & 0.385
  & 1632.0
  & -7.284\\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please edit your example to be a complete document that produces the image so that people can see the issue and test answers,  `\rot` is not defined...

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added: \newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with the `\rothead` command from `makecell`, and a formatting of column heads defined in the preamble. I also suggest using the `S` column type, to align all numbers on the decimal dot. Note  `a4wide`is deprecated and shouldn't be used any more, and the `usenames` option of `xcolor` is now the default.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%, left=2cm, right=3cm
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\itshape}
\setlength{\rotheadsize}{3cm}

  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}X}%

  %%% The line for vertical centering
  \def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
  %%% ------
\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[h!]
  \centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \caption{Table of results}
  \label{tbl:listexperiments}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!18}{white}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cCc*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}S[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=3.1] S[table-format=2.2]ccS[table-format=5.1] S[table-format=-2.3]}
  \rowcolor{gray!40}[\tabcolsep][18.7pt]
  \rothead{Experiment number}
  & \rothead{Time scales}
  & \rothead{Hidden units}
  & {\rothead{Prediction length (samples)}}
  & {\rothead{Sample length (minutes)}}
  & {\rothead{Input sequence length (samples)}}
  &{ \rothead{Model training steps (1000s)}}
  & {\rothead{Training time (hours)}}
  & \rothead{Loss value}
  & \rothead{Next Type Error}
  & {\rothead{Next Switch MSE}}
  & {\rothead{Next Switch RMSE}}\\
  \#721
  & \footnotesize{[1, 32]} & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 80.1 & 14.14 & 0.751 & 0.364 & 1570.8 & -9.043\\
  \#724
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 10.1 & 1.98 & 0.818 & 0.408 & 1707.9 & -8.212\\
  \#727
  & \footnotesize{[1]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 230.1 & 39.51 & 0.838 & 0.346 & 1853.8 & -14.215\\
  \#730
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 180.1 & 33.88 & 0.845 & 0.405 & 1753.2 & -8.222\\
  \#742
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 48 & 14 & 9 & 512 & 5.1 & 0.51 & 0.864 & 0.422 & 1688.2 & -5.685\\
  \#745
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 48 & 14 & 9 & 512 & 1.0 & 0.13 & 1.038 & 0.414 & 2069.8 & -4.907\\
  \#748
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 48 & 14 & 9 & 512 & 22.6 & 2.14 & 0.841 & 0.431 & 1678.6 & -6.614\\
  \#751
  & \footnotesize{[1, 8]}
  & 48 & 14 & 9 & 512 & 2.6 & 0.29 & 0.893 & 0.433 & 1844.3
  & -3.705\\
  \#754
  & \footnotesize{[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 0.1 & 0.13 & 1.254 & 0.461 & 2661.1 & 5.821\\
  \#757
  & \footnotesize{[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 325.1 & 93.51 & 0.814 & 0.381 & 1736.5 & -10.174\\
  \#760
  & \footnotesize{[1, 16]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 60.1 & 11.30 & 0.811 & 0.387 & 1657.5 & -7.984\\
  \#763
  & \footnotesize{[1, 3, 9, 18, 36, 72]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1080 & 45.1 & 11.50 & 0.795 & 0.377 & 1751.9 & -10.839\\
  \#768
  & \footnotesize{[1]}
  & 96 & 5 & 72 & 128 & 245.1 & 8.02 & 1.151 & 0.529 & 26301.8 & -38.075\\
  \#769
  & \footnotesize{[1]}
  & 96 & 5 & 72 & 128 & 47.6 & 1.58 & 1.133 & 0.530 & 25688.5 & -32.278\\
  \#770
  & \footnotesize{[1]}
  & 96 & 14 & 18 & 512 & 87.6 & 8.32 & 1.085 & 0.528 & 10844.1 & -36.840\\
  \#771
  & \footnotesize{[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 15.1 & 4.47 & 0.810 & 0.397 & 1737.2 & -9.246\\
  \#772
  & \footnotesize{[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 17.6 & 5.27 & 0.835 & 0.400 & 1720.5 & -9.170\\
  \#773
  & \footnotesize{[1, 16]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 15.1 & 2.84 & 0.817 & 0.400 & 1658.7 & -7.184\\
  \#774
  & \footnotesize{[1, 64]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 17.6 & 3.23 & 0.877 & 0.393 & 1724.9 & -9.322\\
  \#775
  & \footnotesize{[1, 32]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 22.6 & 4.15 & 0.764 & 0.365 & 1630.3 & -9.681\\
  \#776
  & \footnotesize{[1, 32]}
  & 48 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 1.0 & 0.23 & 1.030 & 0.445 & 2013.5 & -4.622\\
  \#777
  & \footnotesize{[1, 9, 36]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1080 & 35.1 & 7.21 & 0.802 & 0.392 & 1708.3 & -8.549\\
  \#778
  & \footnotesize{[1, 16, 64]}
  & 96 & 14 & 9 & 1024 & 47.6 & 8.94 & 0.747 & 0.385 & 1632.0 & -7.284\\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: good trick withuse of `rowcolor` ! (+1). i prepare almost the same solution, but had problems with coloring of the first row: `\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}  \caption{Table of results}
  \label{tbl:listexperiments}\rowcolors{2}{gray!18}{white}\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\footnotesize}C                    *{3}{S[table-format=2.0]}  S[table-format=4.0]                                     S[table-format=3.1]  S[table-format=2.2] *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]}  S[table-format=5.1]  S[table-format=-2.3] }`

Comment: `makecell` seems to have problems with colours in tables. I don't know exactly what it does that generate this problem. Some times it can be solved with the optional arguments of `columncolor/\rowcolor`, sometimes it can't and we have to do without the package (a typical example, if I remember well, it that the `gape` commands do not work if we use colour in table).

Answer (score 0):

Just define `\rot` to specify the cell format as well:

```
  \newcommand*\rot[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the headers don't nicely align centered with the data in the horizontal direction.

Comment: @Jeroen I used l in the multi column you could use c instead

Comment: That's better, I like that this achieves the desired result while changing only one line. The output looks like: ![Output](https://i.imgur.com/Uqra0eu.png)